# angular7 проблема с повторной инициализацией методов

Tags: angular

Я использую библиотеку Simplewebrtc для создание аудиоконференций.
Короткий пример компонент для создания комнаты.

```
webrtc = new Simplewebrtc({
  localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
  remoteVideosEl: 'remotesVideos',
  autoRequestMedia: true,
  media: {
    video: false, audio: true
  }
});

roomID;

constructor() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.roomID = params['id'].toUpperCase();
    this.initRoom(this.roomID);
  }
}

initRoom(roomID) {
  this.webrtc.on('readyToCall', () => {
    this.webrtc.joinRoom(this.roomID);
  });
}
```

Если я уйду с этого компонента на другой, и заново вернусь к нему, или поменяю только id роутера, то this.webrtc.on('readyToCall', ()...) перестает работать.

Любые подписки this.webrtc.on() инициализируются у меня только раз, возможно я не понимаю жизненно цикла компонента. Могли бы вы мне помочь с этим разобраться?

Comment: судя по документации, нужно вызывать `disconnect()`, потому что `it might reuse the underlying websocket connection`

Comment: Я добавлял в onDestroy(), this.webrtc.disconnect().
Но это приводит ни к каким изменениям

Comment: переспрошу на всякий случай в - `onDestroy` или `ngOnDestroy`?) (мало ли)

Comment: ngOnDestroy(), конечно
Есть ещё момент, если я из компонента room, перейду на главную, то аудиоконференция продолжит свое существование, хотя, как мне кажется, такого быть не должно, ведь компонента больше нет.
Это, конечно, решается в ngOnDestroy -> this.webrtc.leaveRoom()

Comment: я думаю вам нужно шкребать документацию simplewebrtc, другого нечего посоветовать :(

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное время. Я думаю, что проблема может быть в angular, или в моем не понимании жизненногоцикла компонента. Потому что, как мне кажется, после удаления компонента, он должен инициализироваться заново, но мои подписки на события продолжают жить.
Просто, такая же беда и с socket.io

Comment: у всех компонентов разный жизненный цикл, в зависимости от того где он находится и какие директивы к нему применяются

Comment: к тому же вы не отписываетесь от потока `params`, что может привести созданию нового лисенера `readyToCall`

Comment: Изменил route.params.subscribe, так чтобы при destroy отписывался. К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: я не имел в виду, что отписка на 400% решит вашу проблему, ваша задача сейчас исключить любые ботлнеки, которые могут привести к утечкам памяти и соответственно к тому что rtc не дисконектится, к тому же вы уверены на 100% что `ngOnDestroy` вызывается?